# Drawing a big number of images in C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, image, panel, picturebox

I'm creating a map editor for game in C# Windows Forms. What I need is a grid that will have to store even a few thousands of images.

My first approach was to create a `Panel` control and then add multiple `PictureBoxes` to it. Unfortunately 2000 images took about 3 seconds to draw.

Then I decided to try creating `Rectangles` and drawing `Images` on them in `Panel`'s `OnPaint()` method in hope to get better results but it's still very slow.

Is there any better, efficient way to render so many images in Windows Forms?

Thanks in advance for any advices.

Comment: Are all those 2000 images visible on the screen at the same time?

Comment: Yes, they are. And they need to be rendered very fast so that going from one place on map to another wouldn't have to take 3 seconds.

Comment: @Mosquito - What you want isn't realistic.  Why can't you generate the images, then determine, which images you need to display?  I would argue that `3 seconds` is as quick as your going to get.

Comment: Are they scaled? i.e. is each image actually 100x100 but you're showing a 5x5 image?

Comment: @Ramhound - All images are needed, because sometimes I will need to zoom out and look at the map from the distance. Why isn't it realistic? How do other map editors work then?

Comment: @Brad Yes, they are scaled. They're original size is 32x32px but when I zoom out, I need to decrease their size.

Comment: @Mosquito - They don't generate 3,000 images at once, they only generate ( if they generate the images ) they need for a specific view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Paint event as you have done but...

As part of the loading of the images, cache a zoomed out version where you merge 16 images into one, which is only 125 images, when you zoom out over a certain scale, switch to using the pre-rendered zoomed out version.

You can do that as often as you like for multiple zoom levels with the idea of keeping as few images as possible on screen at anyone time. So you could divide it by 4 again.

I do this for a project which has a map comprised of 65536 images (256 x 256). The cache is also writted to disk so each time you zoom out you see the same number of images. In my editior I can only view 16 images at any one time, even if I'm looking at the whole map.

You can further improve on the this by knowing the available options to the user (e.g. Pan and Zoom) this gives you a limited subset of images the user could potentially view next so you can preload these to improve performance.

You'll increased load time initially but I bet you already have a significant load time pulling 2000 images off disk